# Dependency is not being resolved on pub upgrade command

Tags: dart, dart-editor, dart-pub

I have noticed that when I do a pub upgrade certain dependencies are not being resolved as expected - mainly analyzer and args. Please look at the console output for a particular upgrade.

```
    Resolving dependencies.........................................................................
      analyzer 0.10.5 (6 newer versions available)
      animation 0.5.21
      args 0.9.0 (2 newer versions available)
      barback 0.11.0+1
      browser 0.9.1
      collection 0.9.0
      csslib 0.9.2
      custom_element 0.9.1+2
      darmatch 0.2.0
      dartlings 0.2.0
      deequery 0.2.0
      dynamic_object 1.0.4
      event_bus 0.2.4
    > gloss 0.1.3 (was 0.1.2)
      html5_dnd 0.3.5
      html5lib 0.9.1
      html_components 0.1.5
      html_import 0.9.0
      intl 0.9.1 (3 newer versions available)
      js 0.2.1
      jsonx 1.1.1
      logging 0.9.1+1
      model_map 0.2.5
      more 1.0.1
      mutation_observer 0.9.0
      observe 0.9.3
      path 1.0.0
      polymer 0.9.3+2 (2 newer versions available)
      polymer_expressions 0.9.1
      pubsub 1.1.9
      quiver 0.17.0
      roole_element 0.5.0
      shadow_dom 0.9.1
      source_maps 0.9.0
      stack_trace 0.9.1
      styleproc_element 0.2.0
      template_binding 0.9.1
      unittest 0.9.2+1 (1 newer version available)
      unmodifiable_collection 0.9.2
      uri 0.8.0
      utf 0.9.0
      web_widgets 0.0.3
      yaml 0.9.0
    Downloading gloss 0.1.3...
    Changed 1 dependency!
```

Notice that args, analyzer and intl are resolved but the current version is not downloaded and updated like the others.

I am using the following:

Dart Editor version 1.1.0.dev_05_06 (DEV)
Dart SDK version 1.1.0-dev.5.6

Thanks for helping to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This are prerelease updates like `analyzer 0.10.6-5` (see the `-5` which indicates it's the 5th prerelease build)

You have to set your dependency in `pubspec.yaml` to a version number higher than the latest regular build like `analyzer: '>=0.10.6'.
If the dependency is not in your code but in a dependency of your code you have to add the dependency to`dependency_overrides:` in your pubspec.yaml.